# Analysis-Can a set be nowhere dense, first species, and have positive outer content?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a set be nowhere dense, first species, and have positive outer content?  My main problem is that I feel like it is impossible for a set to have positive outer content and be first species, but I have no idea how to go about showing it.

Comment: Is first species the same as first category? What do you mean with outer content?

Comment: First species means that the set can be derived to the empty set given n finite derivations.  Outer content is defined to be the infimum of the sum of open covers of S.  Examples are the following:  outer content of the rationals in [0,1] is 0.  Outer content of the reals in [0,1] is 1.  Voltera savant set has an outer content of 1/2.